# I installed CocoaPods, but it didn't install

Tags: flutter, terminal, cocoapods

I received a message that cocoapods was successfully installed on my MacBook (M1 air). However, when I run flutter doctor in the terminal, a message pops up saying that it is not installed.

[image]

Comment: Is the path to it recognisable from where you run flutter doctor?

Comment: check the error in your provided screenshot before the flutter doctor command that indicates that the there is error installing cocoapods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d8IV.png)

It looks like you didn't install cocoapods successfully